# Schengen C Visa With Swiss Consulate but not Visiting Switzerland

Tags: visas, schengen

We are trying to get Schengen C visa for travel & tourism. Our itinerary does not include Switzerland. However due to availability of slots I would like to book Visa appointment with Switzerland for Schengen C visa.

Will this be a problem?

Basically here's my situation. I am trying to visit France, Italy & Greece. I will stay for substantial durations in all three places. But I will start off with Italy by entering Paris and taking same day flight to Italy. Then go to Greece. From there fly to France and exit europe. French visa appointments are unavailable for two months. What other options do I have? Can I apply with Italy & Greece? They are not my point of entry

Comment: Welcome to Travel Stack Exchange. Could you [edit] that information into your question? Comments are (in theory) only temporary.

Comment: The visa slots are not available for two months. My travel date is in Sep. Appointments are not available till end of Sep. Any ways to get around this? I had all the time on this planet. Did not act because, I did not expect things to be this backlogged. Cant believe no slots are available for two months.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Swiss consulate will refuse to process your application unless it describes a visit for which Switzerland is the main destination.

If you do describe and document such a visit, but don't intend to actually follow the pland you describe, you'll be committing *visa fraud*, which if found out could lead to your visa being annulled, and make if difficult for you to get another visa afterwards.

Comment: That sucks! because France does not specify such requirements. They allow you to apply with it, even if it is not the main country of stay.

Comment: Basically here's my situation. I am trying to visit France, Italy & Greece. I will stay for substantial durations in all three places. But I will start off with Italy by entering Paris and taking same day flight to Italy. Then go to Greece. From there fly to France and exit europe. French visa appointments are unavailable for two months. What other options do I have? Can I apply with Italy & Greece? They are not my point of entry.

Comment: @Ace they may not express those requirements, but they do abide by them.These rules are a central part of the Schengen visa system, and all Schengen states are supposed to observe them.  They are defined in the Schengen Visa Code.  The code requires you to apply based on your main destination. If Italy or Greece is your main destination, you should apply with Italy or Greece.  One criterion, though not the only one, is the length of your stay.

Comment: Thanks @phoog. Italy will be 7 days, Greece and France will be lesser. 3 & 4 days respectively. So its pretty clear then, Italy is what I am must be targeting.

Comment: @Ace, if there is something specific in France they could be the main destination. For example, if you go for a weekend in one country to attend a friend's wedding and a week in another to sit on the beach, the country with the weekend visit would be the *main* destination.